# Installing APK via Terminal Emulator

Tags: terminal

I have installed Android 4.4 through VirtualBox on my PC. I want to know how to install an APK (e.g. FIFA 14) in it via a command in terminal.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ su

# cd (location in which you have the apk file)

# pm install fifa14.apk (or whatever the apk name)
```

Comment: @agharehanabbas You need to put the actual name of the APK file you have instead of `fifa1.apk`.

Comment: @agharehanabbas You also need to put the correct path after `cd`, not just `(location)`. For example, if you have put the .apk file in `/sdcard/`, use `cd /sdcard/`.

Comment: @agharehanabbas inorder to install the apk from terminal emulator you first need to download the apk file. In your case it is fifa14.apk. You need to move the apk file inside your phone sdcard. Then open the terminal and follow the instruction. In cd (location) it has to be `cd /sdcard/(folder name in which you moved the apk)`.